# Vue 2 Laravel 5.3 Bootstrap 4 Accordion

Tags: laravel-5.3, vuejs2, bootstrap-4

Not sure what is wrong, the following code leads to a panel-like card showing the table and the heading but not an interactive accordion. I check the code from inspect it does show exact the same structure as bootstrap example shows. I tried to copy the bootstrap example directly into my Vue but it happens to have problem too but if I put them into view php it works. So what I suspect is that my Vue does not quite read the Bootstrap JS properly. but I already put `require('./bootstrap');` into my app.js I expect that would activate the JS in my Vue too. Please help. Although I do not think the code helps anything but I will still attach it for your reference. It does not seem to be my codes problem.

Item-sorting-liost.vue

```
<template>
   <div>
     <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div v-for="cat in cats" class="card">
          <div class="card-header" role="tab" :id="'heading'+cat.id">

              <a
              data-toggle="collapse" 
              data-parent="#accordion" 
              :href="'#collapse'+cat.id" 
              aria-expanded="false" 
              :aria-controls="'collapse'+cat.id"
              >
                {{cat.name}}
              </a>
          </div>

          <div :id="'collapse'+cat.id" class="collapse in" role="tabpanel" :aria-labelledby="'heading'+cat.id">
            <ul class="list-group">
              <li
              v-for="subcat in subcats" 
              v-if="subcat.category_id == cat.id" 
              class="list-group-item"
              >
                <a 
                :name="subcat.name" 
                href="" 
                @click.prevent="getSelectedSubcatProducts(subcat.id)"
                >{{subcat.name}}</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a late answer, but it's difficult to get jQuery and Vue to play nicely with each other for various reasons better described here: http://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/

If you'd like to use Bootstrap in Vue.js, I recommend utilizing [BootstrapVue](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it is hard for me to prove whether it is good to use anymore. I will give you an upvote! thanks for the contribution.